# Keep parent loading whilst react query in child component is loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a parent component in my react app that makes a call to our api, and the page has a loader whilst its waiting for response. On response, I loop through the data, and I pass each iteration into a child component, that then makes another request based on that data.

Is there a way to keep the parent spinner going, until the child data is loaded?

Currently, it displays the parent, then a split second later, some data attached to the child pops in and its not great for the user.

I am using reactQuery for my api calls.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of how your code is loading? There's a bunch of ways to solve this, depending on how you are structuring your code...

Comment: Also, more details about how your code is structured and what your needs are for user experience would help as well. (Often, loading components as soon as you have partial data is a good thing as a default, so it might help to explain why it isn't here).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [useIsFetching](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useIsFetching) for that or dive into [suspense](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/suspense). But the first one should work just fine for what you describe.